# Inserting JSON object in MySQL in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I am working on inserting a `JSON object` in `JSON-type MySQL column`.

Sample data that I am trying to insert is like this:

[image: sample data]

**Sample Laravel code**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $layaway = new Layaway;

    foreach($request->selected_products as $p) {
        $layaway->selected_products = json_encode([
            'id' => $p['id'],
            'sku' => $p['sku'],
            'name' => $p['name'],
            'image' => $p['image'],
            'description' => $p['description'],
            'category_id' => $p['category_id'],
            'regular_price' => $p['regular_price']
        ]);

    }

    $layaway->save();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Layaway Program has been successfully saved!'
    ]);

}
```

**Sample response from dd()**

[image: sample result]

**Question**
How can I save all of the data in the `$request->selected_products` into my `MYSQL json-type column`?

Comment: why don't just `json_encode($request->selected_products)` and then save it to `$layaway->selected_products`? saves you a for loop.

Comment: Thank you. it is working. I don't know that it is just as easy as that. silly me.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comment by Wreigh,

I just changed this code:

```
foreach($request->selected_products as $p) {
    $layaway->selected_products = json_encode([
        'id' => $p['id'],
        'sku' => $p['sku'],
        'name' => $p['name'],
        'image' => $p['image'],
        'description' => $p['description'],
        'category_id' => $p['category_id'],
        'regular_price' => $p['regular_price']
    ]);

}
```

into this code:

```
$layaway->selected_products = json_encode($request->selected_products);
```

Thank you.